# How to avoid user to enter same information again after edit?

Tags: php, edit

For example : user wan to change password, but enter the same password with existing.

How I can avoid user to enter same information again ?

Anyone can provide example code ? Please help.

Comment: checking the new value against the old value, and post your code first

Comment: Possible duplicate of your later (now closed) question: [How to editing information is not the same as re-entering information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475250/how-to-editing-information-is-not-the-same-as-re-entering-information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check using something like this :

```
if( $oldPassword == $newPassword )
{ 
   // do something (like echo "same password can't be used again"; )

}
else
{
   // change password in the database
}
```

Comment: This does not work for even older passwords.

Comment: Also, you should not be storing old passwords in plain text - though they should not do so, users will often entrust to you high-value passwords even if your use case is not high-value. Always use a decent hashing and salting system to store passwords - see the PHP manual.